# JavaScript value of an empty form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want to validate an HTML form to ensure an `<input>` has a value. In JavaScript, what is the value of an empty field in a form: `null` or the empty string (`""`)?

Comment: did you try to see for yourself what it was???

Comment: Seems like it would be fairly simple to test both of these methods. Did you try it already and are getting ambiguous results?

Comment: SO shouldn't be your first choice. Try yourself and if you think you are unable to find out and you really need a help, try SO. Help keep SO clean.

Comment: You could always alert or log `document.getElementById(idname).value` to see the value.

Comment: No I didn't try it myself.  There are a lot of examples online that give different answers, so I wanted to ask the experts, in case there are cross-browser compatibility issues or other snafus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any input element, `value` is **always** a string.  This means you can expect it to be `""`, when empty.

See the docs for [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLInputElement) on the Mozilla Developer Network, or the relevant part of the [HTML4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-49531485).

Answer (score 0):

Empty string, if it's a text field.

Answer (score 0):

It's an empty string -- one of the beautiful perks of JavaScript.